# Include MX library to Flash CS5 project

Tags: actionscript-3, import, flash-cs5

I need to use some classes belong to `mx` library, but when I try to import it Flash throws me an error that it can't find this library.

How can I import it to my project? I'm using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try downloading the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK), get mx.swc from Flex\frameworks\lib and add it to your library path (ActionScript Settings > Library Path) in Flash CS5.