# Cannot find mx libraries for flash cs6

Tags: flash, apache-flex

What i have done so far is downloaded The Flex SDK this is the article that i found that i thought might help.

[Include MX library to Flash CS5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913822/include-mx-library-to-flash-cs5-project)

But i couldn't find the file in the lib folder to import into flash CS6.

Can anyone help please, the library I'm looking for is mx.utils.Delegate

What I'm trying to do is develop live streaming with flash using iOS camera and embedding this swf file into iOS objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and you don't need to import that library in AS3 only in AS2 but I'm using 3 so problem solved lol